# Include full file path in esbuild compiled output

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, esbuild

I want to get this file as a es module in my browser.
HelloApp.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

function HelloApp(props: any): React.ReactElement {
  return <div>Greetings</div>
}

render(
  <HelloApp />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I'm running `npx esbuild ./**/*.tsx --outdir=esbuilt --format=esm`

Output:

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
function HelloApp(props) {
  return /* @__PURE__ */ React.createElement("div", null, "I'm a component");
}
render(/* @__PURE__ */ React.createElement(HelloApp, null), document.getElementById("app"));
```

These imports aren't usable by the browser. Ideally, the path would be something like `import React from "/scripts/react.js"`

How do you tell esbuild to write imports like that?

Answer (score 0):

The imports cannot be resolved as they are not included in the bundle. This should work if you add the --bundle argument. Also, you should use a specific file as the entry point for the bundle instead of passing a glob pattern.

Example:

```
npx esbuild src/app.tsx --bundle --outdir=esbuilt --format=esm
```

When generating a bundle, instead of --outdir you can use the --outfile argument to define the bundle file name. You probably also want to minify the bundle for the browser with the --minify argument, specify the target environment for the browsers you want to support with --target and you might want to add sourcemap support with --sourcemap.

The build command becomes:

```
npx esbuild src/app.tsx --bundle --minify --sourcemap --target=chrome58,firefox57,safari11,edge16 --outfile=esbuilt/app.js --format=esm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using snowpack now for imports. My site has a lot of shared resources between pages, so I don't want to bundle. I want my imports to work in the browser.